# Find the constant K in probability distribution?

Tags: probability

[image]

> Find the constant K? 
>   I know how to find K, if there is only one "k" in the question and the rest are given number. I know that all the x value are add upto 1.

But in this question, I don't know how to start.

> One thing I know is $\Sigma(x)=1(k)+2(2k)+3(3k)+4(4k)+5(5k)$ 
>   
> Does this help to find the constant k?

Please help me "Find the constant k" 
Appreciate your help.

Comment: Well, note that as X can either be one of 1,2,3,4,5, then the probability of X being either of them is 1. You know the rest~

Comment: sorry! No, I don't know. Confusing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confused. It's pretty fine. Please note that $X=i$ means ***the event that X equals i***. So, let me interpret the table for you.

> There's a probability of $k$ that event $X=1$ shall happen.
>   There's a probability of $2k$ that event $X=2$ shall happen.
>   There's a probability of $3k$ that event $X=3$ shall happen.
>   There's a probability of $4k$ that event $X=4$ shall happen.
>   There's a probability of $5k$ that event $X=5$ shall happen.
>   No other events are possible.

***Important:*** By [Unitarity of probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Second_axiom), the probability of $Pr({\text{$X$ = 1,2,3,4 or 5}})=1$.

$X=1, X=2, X=3, X=4, X=5$ are five [mutually exclusive events](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_exclusive_events) in the sample space, and there are no other events. So, $$Pr(X=1,2,3,4,5)=\sum_{i=1}^5Pr(X=i)=k+2k+3k+4k+5k = 15k$$

So, what's $k$?

Answer (score -2):

1. $k+2k+3k+k=1$
   (combine terms)
2. $7k=1$
   (move 7 to other side)
3. $k=\frac{1}{7}$

Comment: Step 1 is incorrect. It should be $k+2k+3k+4k+5k=1$. Step 2 should be $15k=1$. Step 3 should be $k=\frac 1 {15}$.